# IE7 issue with text alignment

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, css-position

I have a set of columns on my site. Each item is an `<a>` within an `<li>` and a member of an `<ul>`. The columns are set up so that the top-most `<li>` has a different class from the lower `<li>`'s in the same list (`<ul>`).

In IE7, the top `<li>` element will not align appropriately with it's lower neighboring `<li>`'s.

Here is how it should look (Latest version of Google Chrome):

[image: I Love Google Chrome]

Here is how it looks in IE7 (looks fine in >=IE8):

[image: I Hate IE7]

**Don't mind sizing differences.*

Here is the trimmed HTML for a single column

```
 <div class="map-col" id="map-2">
    <ul class="site-map">
      <li><a class="map-upper">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="map-lower">Wood Fencing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="map-lower">Ornamental Iron</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="map-lower">Gates and Openers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="map-lower">Restoration</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS (I pulled out anything that didn't have to do with positioning --such as font-weight and font-size-- for readability)

```
.site-map{display:inline;}

.map-col{display:block; width:150px;}
.map-upper{text-align:left;}
.map-lower{*text-align:left;}


#map-1{float:left;}
#map-2{float:left;}
#map-3{float:left;}
#map-4{float:left;}
```

As far as it seems to me, IE7 just doesn't like when two separate CSS classes are appended to a single list.

Comment: If you can't find solution then try `position: absolute; left: 0` in place of `text-align: left`. Also you need to give positioning to the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. For anyone with this issue in the future here is the simple fix:

It appears that IE7 has an indentation/margin bug on list elements. To get around this, the  I modified the `<li>` elements to have a defined width of 100% so that they will fill the entire area of the `<ul>`. This allows the text to be left aligned correctly.

Added the following:

`.site-map li{display:block; width:100%; text-align:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Don't define text-align property for anchor tags.. Use it in LI. i.e

```
ul.site-map li{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. It did, however help me find the answer. Thanks!